# USB dongle of CC2540 (for BLE )with Linux...?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on BLE on CC2540 chip i am using TI stack. I have CC2540 Dongle and loaded HostTest.hex from TI into it. Now is that possible to control it from linux system through USB using hcitool?? When it connected with linux system ttyACM0 node created so i attached it with hciattach command and its going success but when i am doing hcicong -a no BD address coming below is logs

```
vijay@vijay:~$ sudo hciattach /dev/ttyACM0 any 115200 flow 
Device setup complete

vijay@vijay:~$ hciconfig -a
    hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:15 acl:0 sco:0 events:1 errors:0
    TX bytes:4 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:0
```

So anyone can help me on what is problem??

Comment: That dongle connects as a serial device.  You can send serial commands to do different things, but I don't think hcitool can utilize it in that mode.  You may have to reflash it with a different hex for it to work as a more "normal" bluetooth dongle that hcitool is expecting.

Comment: HostTest.hex image from TI by that only possible to commutcate with USB as created ACM node..this can be test with host PC but i am getting above problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hciattach /dev/ttyACM0 texas 115200 noflow
```